# Provides implicit functions for a code block in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

Suppose a class defines an implicit function that converts an integer to a String:

```
class Dollar() {
  implicit def currency(num: Int): String = "$" + num.toString

  def apply(body: => Unit) {
    body
  }
}
```

and we also have a function that prints a number transformed by the implicit function:

```
def printAmount(num: Int)(implicit currency: Int => String) {
  println(currency(num))
}
```

then we can call the method `printAmount()` in the constructor of the class `Dollar`:

```
val dollar = new Dollar {
  printAmount(32) // prints "$32"
}
```

However, if we want to provide the implicit function for a code block, a compilation error occurs because the implicit value does not applied:

```
dollar {
  printAmount(14) // Error: No implicit view available from Int => String
}
```

As I know, Groovy has a keyword `use` for the case like this. Is there any way to provide implicit functions for a certain code block in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change dollar such that it takes a function from a conversion function to `Unit`.

```
dollar(f:(Int => String) => Unit) = {
  //...
}
```

Then you can use dollar like this:

```
dollar ( implicit conversion => {
  printAmount(14)
})
```

Comment: Good, thanks. Is there any way to reduce `implicit conversion =>`? It feels a bit verbose for me. `new Dollar { printAmount(32) }` is quite concise already.

Comment: No, there isn't, and there shouldn't be. Otherwise you'd never know which implicits you have in scope.